# 'self' used in method call 'getBooks' before all stored properties are initialized

Tags: ios, rx-swift

when I call getBooks() to init in HomeViewModel make this error ===> 'self' used in method call 'getBooks' before all stored properties are initialized

> this is init

```
init() {
    
    getBooks()
    filterModelObservable = searchValueBehavior
        .map { $0 }
        .throttle(.milliseconds(500), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .withLatestFrom(homeModelSubject) { searchValue, books in
            searchValue.isEmpty ? books : books.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchValue.lowercased()) }
        }
}
```

> this is getBooks() function

```
func getBooks() {
    loadingBehavior.accept(true)
    let url = "https://simple-books-api.glitch.me/books"
    APIServices.instance.getData(url: url, method: .get, params: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil) {[weak self] (bookModel: [Book]?, baseError: HomeBaseError?, error) in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.loadingBehavior.accept(false)
        if let error = error {
            //handler(false, "Error message\(error.localizedDescription.description)")
            print("this is error discription\(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else if let baseError = baseError {
            //handler(false,baseError.error)
            print(baseError.error)
        } else {
            guard let bookModel = bookModel else { return }
            //handler(true, "Success")
            if bookModel.count  > 0 {
                self.homeModelSubject.onNext(bookModel)
                self.isTableHidden.accept(false)
            } else {
                self.isTableHidden.accept(true)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The error *before all stored properties are initialized* means what it says. Before calling `self.getBooks` all properties without a default value must be initialized. I guess the stored property is `filterModelObservable` so first initialize `filterModelObservable` and then call `getBooks()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to indiscriminately mix imperative code with Rx code. You have too many Subjects and Relays in your class and that's making the job you are trying to accomplish much harder than it needs to be... Check this out:

```swift
class HomeViewModel {
    let filterModelObservable: Observable<[Book]>
    let isLoading: Observable<Bool>
    let isTableHidden: Observable<Bool>
    let homeModel: Observable<[Book]>
    
    var searchValueObserver: AnyObserver<String?> { searchValueBehavior.asObserver() }
    private let searchValueBehavior = BehaviorSubject<String?>(value: "")
    
    init() {
        let url = "https://simple-books-api.glitch.me/books"
        homeModel = APIServices.instance.rx_getData(url: url, method: .get, params: nil, encoding: .default, headers: nil)
            .catch { error in
                print("this is error discription\(error.localizedDescription)")
                return .just([])
            }
            .share()
        
        isLoading = homeModel
            .map { _ in false }
            .startWith(true)
        
        isTableHidden = homeModel
            .map { $0.isEmpty }
        
        filterModelObservable = Observable.combineLatest(
            searchValueBehavior
                .map { $0 ?? "" }
                .startWith("")
                .throttle(.milliseconds(500), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance),
            homeModel
        )
        .map { searchValue, books in
            searchValue.isEmpty ? books : books.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchValue.lowercased()) }
        }
    }
}

extension APIServices {
    func rx_getData(url: String, method: Method, params: [String: String]?, encoding: JSONEncoding, headers: [String: String]?) -> Observable<[Book]> {
        Observable.create { [self] observer in
            getData(url: url, method: method, params: params, encoding: encoding, headers: headers) { books, baseError, error in
                if let books = books {
                    observer.onNext(books)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }
                else {
                    observer.onError(error ?? baseError?.error ?? RxError.unknown)
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how I defined an `rx_getData` extension that does the bare minimum needed for the network call and immediately turns it into an Observable rather than trying to do a bunch of work in the closure.

By doing that, we can define all dynamic behavior of the other Observables at creation time...

The `isLoading` observable starts with true and then emits false when the homeModel emits. That can be plainly seen in its definition.

The `isTableHidden` emits when the network request comes back; True if the array is empty and false if it isn't.

The `filterModelObservable` works as well.

Notice how clear the code is and how you only have to look at one place to figure out everything you need to know about a particular property of the view model.

If you stop overusing Subjects and Relays, your code will be much more clear and understandable.